# Recommendations for unit testing when using Subsonic 3.0 LINQ templates

Tags: linq, unit-testing, subsonic, subsonic3

I have started using [Subsonic](http://subsonicproject.com/) for a side project and have been loving using it. Simply a blast. I started off wanting to use the *LINQ* T4 Templates but have since switched to the [ActiveRecord](http://subsonicproject.com/docs/Using_ActiveRecord) templates due to testability. It is very clear how to write unit tests using the active record templates but for the *LINQ* templates there is no clear testing mechanism. I have searched the docs but was wondering if anyone had recommendations for how to do this.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Testing is built in to the active record stuff, but not for the Linq templates - you'd want to abstract those against a Repository or some such. Have a look at the MVC Storefront for a series on how to do this.

Comment: Thanks Rob, I will look at the MVC Storefront for how it is done. Any plans to bake this functionality into the LINQ Templates?